# How to detect auto scroll only user's scrolling?

Tags: javascript

First I just want navigation bar hide or show when I am scrolling

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Handle dropdown show and hide events
  // Autohide functionality for the navbar
  const el_autohide = document.querySelector(".autohide");
  const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
  if (el_autohide) {
    const navbar_height = navbar.offsetHeight;
    document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + "px";

    let last_scroll_top = 0;
    // Listen for scroll events
    window.addEventListener("wheel", function (event) {
      const scroll_top = window.scrollY;
      //   Determine scroll direction and apply corresponding classes
      if (scroll_top < last_scroll_top || scroll_top == 0) {
        el_autohide.classList.remove("scrolled-up");
        el_autohide.classList.add("scrolled-down");
      } else {
        el_autohide.classList.remove("scrolled-down");
        el_autohide.classList.add("scrolled-up");
      }
      last_scroll_top = scroll_top;
    });
  }
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".navbar .dropdown")
    .forEach(function (everydropdown) {
      everydropdown.addEventListener("shown.bs.dropdown", function () {
        el_autohide.classList.remove("scrolled-up");
        el_autohide.classList.add("scrolled-down");
        // Create a dark overlay when the dropdown is shown
        const overlay = document.createElement("div");
        overlay.className = "screen-darken";
        document.body.appendChild(overlay);
        navbar.style.position = "fixed";
        navbar.style.width = "100%";
        // Prevent scrolling when the overlay is active
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
      });
      everydropdown.addEventListener("hide.bs.dropdown", function () {
        // Remove the dark overlay when the dropdown is hidden
        const overlay = document.querySelector(".screen-darken");
        if (overlay) {
          document.body.removeChild(overlay);
        }
        navbar.style.position = "initial";
        // Allow scrolling when the overlay is removed
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
      });
    });
});
```

I used this code and it works but it has a problem when I add image sliders that images' height are not equal. Then navigation bar it's auto hide and show by I didn't scroll the element.

I expect that navigation bar will hide and show when only scrolling by user.